# VueJS: Re-create component after clicking on the same "router-link"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

With vue.js and vue-router, is there a way to re-create a component after clicking on a "router-link" that leads to the same route as the current route?

Basically, it would be great if a click on a "router-link" that leads to the current route could restart the function "created ()" or "mounted ()" of my component.

Maybe there is a trick with "$watch", or something like that, I really don't know!

Comment: Maybe you could just add a method that does what you want on the click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To let Vue distinguish that the component is not the same one as before, you should give the component a key attribute. When the key changes vue recreates the component, so you need something unique to the routes, such as url for example. On this sand box you can see the created hook being run everytime the key changes.

https://codesandbox.io/s/6xmymlpvwk

Comment: It works thanks!
Just to clarify: my event that changes the "key" is placed on a "router-link", so I had to add it like this: @click.native="myEvent"

Comment: Yes, ```<router-view :key="this.$route.path" />```